# Vue.js 2 + Webpack, V-Model Binds and loading data from router.params with optional default not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, webpack

V-Model Binds and loading data from router.params with optional default not working Vue.js 2

I have 4 selects and 1 text input

in my data() method i return an array with the default values for the selects option elements.

what i want is when the component loads to get the values from the url (router.params) and then select the correct value from the select and also display the text input (passed through router params) back in the text box [search box]

I have tried a two way bind, a one way bind, a jquery update using the setTimeout function, but still no positive results

I look forward to your responses and advice, Thank you.

routes

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HomeScreen from '@/components/HomeScreen'
import MangaSearch from '@/components/MangaSearch'
import MangaView from '@/components/MangaView'
import MangaHeaderMenuComponent from '@/components/reusable/MainMenuComponent'
import MangaSearchComponent from '@/components/reusable/MangaSearchComponent'
import MangaPopularComponent from '@/components/reusable/MangaPopularComponent'
import MangaResultsComponent from '@/components/reusable/MangaResultsComponent'

Vue.component('manga-header-menu', MangaHeaderMenuComponent)
Vue.component('manga-search', MangaSearchComponent)
Vue.component('manga-popular', MangaPopularComponent)
Vue.component('manga-results', MangaResultsComponent)

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HomeScreen',
      component: HomeScreen
    },
    {
      path: '/search',
      name: 'MangaSearch',
      component: MangaSearch
    },
    {
      path: '/manga/view',
      name: 'MangaView',
      component: MangaView
    },
  ]
})
```

code below:

```
    <template>
    <div class="search-container">
         <div class="search-form-container">
            <input type="text" v-on:keypress.enter="search" id="q" col="10" placeholder="Search Here" />
        </div>
        <div class="search-filter-container">
            <div><select id="search-genre" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Genre</option>
                    <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:value="genre"> {{ genre }}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div><select id="search-date" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Date</option>
                    <option v-for="date in dates" v-bind:value="date"> {{ date }}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div><select id="search-rating" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Rating</option>
                    <option v-for="rating in ratings" v-bind:value="rating"> {{ rating }}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div><select id="search-language" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Language</option>
                    <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:value="language"> {{ language }}</option>
            </select></div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data (){
        return {
            /* Filter Options */
            /* - Genre List*/
            genres: [ 'All', 'Action', '' ],
            /* - Date/Time Frame List*/
            dates: [ 'All', 'Last Month', 'Last Year'],
            /* - Ratings List*/
            ratings: [ 'All','0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ],
            /* - Language List*/
            languages: [ 'All', 'Afrikaans','Albanian','Amharic','Arabic','Bahasa','Bengali','Bosnian','Bravanese','Bulgarian','Catalan','Chinese (Simplified)','Chinese (Trad–HK)','Chinese (Traditional)','Croatian','Czech','Danish','Dutch','Estonian','Euro English','Farsi','Finnish','French (Belgian)','French (Canadian)','French (Euro)','German','Greek','Gujarati','Haitian Creole','Hebrew','Hindi','Hmong','Hungarian','Icelandic','Italian','Japanese','Javanese','Kashmiri','Kazakh','Khmer','Korean','Laotian','Latvian','Lithuanian','Macedonian','Malay','Malayalam','Mandinka','Marathi','Norwegian','Oromo','Polish','Portuguese','Punjabi','Romanian','Russian','Serbian','Sinhalese','Slovak','Somali','Spanish (Iberian)','Spanish (Latin)','Sudanese Arabic','Swedish','Tagalog','Tamil','Telegu','Thai','Turkish','Ukrainian','Urdu','Vietnamese' ],

            /* Local Storage For Filter Values */
            name: (this.$route.params.name ? this.$route.params.name : ''),
            genre: (this.$route.params.genre ? this.$route.params.genre : 'Genre'),
            date: (this.$route.params.date ? this.$route.params.date : 'Date'),
            rating: (this.$route.params.rating ? this.$route.params.rating : 'Rating'),
            language: (this.$route.params.language ? this.$route.params.language : 'Language')
        };
        return data;
    },
    methods: {
        search (){
            this.$router.push({
                path: 'search',
                query: {
                    name: $('#q').val(),
                    genre: $('#search-genre').val(),
                    date: $('#search-date').val(),
                    rating: $('#search-rating').val(),
                    language: $('#search-language').val()
                }
            });
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried a two way bind, a one way bind, a jquery update using the setTimeout function.

Comment: Can you add url you are trying to access this route with

Comment: @NafeesAnwar this.$router.push

it will push this url is

http://localhost:8080/#/search?name=SearchTest&genre=All&date=All&rating=All&language=All

Comment: @NafeesAnwar v-on:keypress.enter="search"   calls the search method which then loads the search route

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Show `search` route definition, please.

Comment: @Styx please see updated description for my routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have numerous issue with this code:

1. You don't use Vue's reactivity.
2. You read route `params`, but redirect with `query` (it works, but could cause issues in future in case you'll change route *params*)
3. You don't assign parameters fetched from route to your form fields.

---

First, add `filter: {}` to `data` (it will store current filter fields) and let's update it by route change:

```js
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // filter options omitted for better readability
        // ...
        filter: {},
      };
    },
    watch: {
      '$route'(to) {
        if (to.name === 'MangaSearch') {
          this.filter = Object.assign({}, to.query);
        }
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.filter = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);
    },
    methods: {
      search() {
        this.$router.push({
          path: '/search',
          query: this.filter
        });
      }
    },
  }
```

Next, let's link form fields with this filter using `v-model`:

```html
<div class="search-form-container">
    <input type="text" v-model="filter.name" @keypress.enter="search" id="q" col="10" placeholder="Search Here" />
</div>
<div class="search-filter-container">
    <div><select v-model="filter.genre" id="search-genre" class="search-filter-field">
        <option disabled>Genre</option>
        <option v-for="genre in genres" :value="genre">{{ genre }}</option>
    </select></div>
    <div><select v-model="filter.date" id="search-date" class="search-filter-field">
        <option disabled>Date</option>
        <option v-for="date in dates" :value="date">{{ date }}</option>
    </select></div>
    <div><select v-model="filter.rating" id="search-rating" class="search-filter-field">
        <option disabled>Rating</option>
        <option v-for="rating in ratings" :value="rating">{{ rating }}</option>
    </select></div>
    <div><select v-model="filter.language" id="search-language" class="search-filter-field">
        <option disabled>Language</option>
        <option v-for="language in languages" :value="language">{{ language }}</option>
    </select></div>
</div>
```

That's all. You don't even need jQuery anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access query params from `params` attribute. Query parameters are in `query` attribute not in `params`. You can use two way binding and pre-select the correct value like this.

```
    <select :v-model="genre" id="search-genre" class="search-filter-field">
      <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Genre</option>
      <option v-for="g in genres" v-bind:value="g"> {{ g }}</option>
    </select>
```

And in data

```
genre: this.$route.query.genre,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not using Vue's reactivity. There's a few things to update here:

- Replace jQuery with Vue data properties
- Add `v-model` to your form fields
- Use `router.replace` instead of `router.push` (avoids browser back/forward reacting to search changes)

```js
const Search = {
  template: "#search",
  data() {
    return {
      /* Filter Options */
      /* - Genre List*/
      genres: ["All", "Action", ""],
      /* - Date/Time Frame List*/
      dates: ["All", "Last Month", "Last Year"],
      /* - Ratings List*/
      ratings: ["All", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
      /* - Language List*/
      languages: [
        "All",
        "Afrikaans",
        "Albanian",
        "Amharic",
        "Arabic",
        "Bahasa",
        "Bengali",
        "Bosnian",
        "Bravanese",
        "Bulgarian",
        "Catalan",
        "Chinese (Simplified)",
        "Chinese (Trad–HK)",
        "Chinese (Traditional)",
        "Croatian",
        "Czech",
        "Danish",
        "Dutch",
        "Estonian",
        "Euro English",
        "Farsi",
        "Finnish",
        "French (Belgian)",
        "French (Canadian)",
        "French (Euro)",
        "German",
        "Greek",
        "Gujarati",
        "Haitian Creole",
        "Hebrew",
        "Hindi",
        "Hmong",
        "Hungarian",
        "Icelandic",
        "Italian",
        "Japanese",
        "Javanese",
        "Kashmiri",
        "Kazakh",
        "Khmer",
        "Korean",
        "Laotian",
        "Latvian",
        "Lithuanian",
        "Macedonian",
        "Malay",
        "Malayalam",
        "Mandinka",
        "Marathi",
        "Norwegian",
        "Oromo",
        "Polish",
        "Portuguese",
        "Punjabi",
        "Romanian",
        "Russian",
        "Serbian",
        "Sinhalese",
        "Slovak",
        "Somali",
        "Spanish (Iberian)",
        "Spanish (Latin)",
        "Sudanese Arabic",
        "Swedish",
        "Tagalog",
        "Tamil",
        "Telegu",
        "Thai",
        "Turkish",
        "Ukrainian",
        "Urdu",
        "Vietnamese"
      ],

      /* Local Storage For Filter Values */
      name: this.$route.params.name ? this.$route.params.name : "",
      genre: this.$route.params.genre ? this.$route.params.genre : "Genre",
      date: this.$route.params.date ? this.$route.params.date : "Date",
      rating: this.$route.params.rating ? this.$route.params.rating : "Rating",
      language: this.$route.params.language
        ? this.$route.params.language
        : "Language"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      this.$router.replace({
        path: "/search",
        query: {
          name: this.name,
          genre: this.genre,
          date: this.date,
          rating: this.rating,
          language: this.language
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
   {
     path: '/',
      redirect: '/search'
    },
    {
      path: "/search",
      component: Search
    }
  ]
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  #App
  <router-view />
</div>

<template id="search">
  <div class="search-container">
    <div class="search-form-container">
      <input v-model="name" type="text" v-on:keypress.enter="search" id="q" col="10" placeholder="Search Here" />
    </div>
    <div class="search-filter-container">
      <div>
        <select @change="search" id="search-genre" class="search-filter-field">
          <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Genre</option>
          <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:value="genre"> {{ genre }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
      <div>
        <select @change="search" id="search-date" class="search-filter-field">
          <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Date</option>
          <option v-for="date in dates" v-bind:value="date"> {{ date }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select @change="search" id="search-rating" class="search-filter-field">
          <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Rating</option>
          <option v-for="rating in ratings" v-bind:value="rating"> {{ rating }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select @change="search" id="search-language" class="search-filter-field">
          <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Language</option>
          <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:value="language"> {{ language }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: @Styx this solve the issue, using v-model on all fields....
however the v-model="name" doesn't work... it displays in the url on the replace and all the filters work correctly, however the name (#q) field is still empty

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Read my answer below, it solves all your issues and is more clean.

Comment: @Styx That's a matter of preference. I tend avoid `watch`es. Why watch a whole object that you won't need to react to 90% of the time.

Comment: @Kordonme I understand, though I prefer to cover all situations. For example, clicking Back/Forward in browser ;)

Answer (score 0):

working script, Thank you guys!!!

```
<template>
    <div class="search-container">
        <div class="search-form-container">
            <input v-model="filter.name" type="text" @change="search" id="q" col="10" placeholder="Search Here" />
       </div>
    <div class="search-filter-container">
            <div><select @change="search" v-model="filter.genre" id="search-genre" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Genre</option>
                    <option v-for="genre in genres" v-bind:value="genre"> {{ genre }}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div><select @change="search" v-model="filter.date" id="search-date" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Date</option>
                    <option v-for="date in dates" v-bind:value="date"> {{ date }}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div><select @change="search" v-model="filter.rating" id="search-rating" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Rating</option>
                    <option v-for="rating in ratings" v-bind:value="rating"> {{ rating }}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div><select @change="search" v-model="filter.language" id="search-language" class="search-filter-field">
                    <option :disabled="true" :selected="true">Language</option>
                    <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:value="language"> {{ language }}</option>
            </select></div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data (){
        return {
            genres: [ 'All', 'Action', '' ],
            dates: [ 'All', 'Last Month', 'Last Year'],
            ratings: [ 'All','0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ],
            languages: [ 'All', 'Afrikaans','Albanian','Amharic','Arabic','Bahasa','Bengali','Bosnian','Bravanese','Bulgarian','Catalan','Chinese (Simplified)','Chinese (Trad–HK)','Chinese (Traditional)','Croatian','Czech','Danish','Dutch','Estonian','Euro English','Farsi','Finnish','French (Belgian)','French (Canadian)','French (Euro)','German','Greek','Gujarati','Haitian Creole','Hebrew','Hindi','Hmong','Hungarian','Icelandic','Italian','Japanese','Javanese','Kashmiri','Kazakh','Khmer','Korean','Laotian','Latvian','Lithuanian','Macedonian','Malay','Malayalam','Mandinka','Marathi','Norwegian','Oromo','Polish','Portuguese','Punjabi','Romanian','Russian','Serbian','Sinhalese','Slovak','Somali','Spanish (Iberian)','Spanish (Latin)','Sudanese Arabic','Swedish','Tagalog','Tamil','Telegu','Thai','Turkish','Ukrainian','Urdu','Vietnamese' ],


            /* Local Storage For Filter Values */
            filter: {
                    name: this.$route.query.name ? this.$route.query.name : "",
              genre: this.$route.query.genre ? this.$route.query.genre : "Genre",
              date: this.$route.query.date ? this.$route.query.date : "Date",
              rating: this.$route.query.rating ? this.$route.query.rating : "Rating",
              language: this.$route.query.language ? this.$route.query.language : "Language"
            }
        };
        return data;
    },
    watch: {
      '$route'(to) {
        if (to.name === 'MangaSearch') {
                    filter.name = to.query.name ? to.query.name : "",
                    filter.genre = to.query.genre ? to.query.genre : "Genre",
                    filter.date = to.query.date ? to.query.date : "Date",
                    filter.rating = to.query.rating ? to.query.rating : "Rating",
                    filter.language = to.query.language  ? to.query.language : "Language"
        }
      },
    },
    created() {
                filter.name = this.$route.query.name ? this.$route.query.name : "",
                filter.genre = this.$route.query.genre ? this.$route.query.genre : "Genre",
                filter.date = this.$route.query.date ? this.$route.query.date : "Date",
                filter.rating = this.$route.query.rating ? this.$route.query.rating : "Rating",
                filter.language = this.$route.query.language ? this.$route.query.language : "Language"
    },
    methods: {
    search() {
      this.$router.replace({
        path: "/search",
        query: this.filter
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @NafeesAnwar this is my new working version, thank you for your support and guidance, I used pieces from both of y'all examples...Thank you once again

Comment: @Styx this this is my new working version, thank you for your support and guidance, I used pieces from both of y'all examples...Thank you once again

Comment: @Kordonme  this is my new working version, thank you for your support and guidance, I used pieces from both of y'all examples...Thank you once again

Comment: You don't need to fill `filter` in `data()` as it's filled in `created()` and `watch`. You don't need to add "defaults" also, because for selects they won't work and for input empty value is the same as empty string. And if you remove those defaults you'll eventually get the same version of script as I've shown :)